# loading JPEG image into matrix form in android and do processing

Tags: java, android, eclipse, opencv, image-processing

I am almost beginner in android and JAVA and I have a problem for loading an image using OpenCV 2_4_9 .
I used Highgui.imread but the program stops when it goes to this line. I want the program to load image from a folder into matrix form
the line I used is

```
String outdir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath().concat("/storage/ABB");  

String latestFile = outdir.concat("/VARI.jpg");  

Mat im_rgb = Highgui.imread(latestFile,0)
```

please please help me

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "the program stops"? Does it produce an error message? Did you run in in a debugger?

Comment: What should happen after the file was loaded? What do you do after loading the file? provide some more context and I think you should add a semicolon to the end of your third line.

Comment: I am using Eclipse and I run it in my phone debugger.
It stops when it reaches to the line of imread as I see in LogCat

Comment: The smicolon is okay.
I commented the whole processing part and just I need to load the image so I can do the processing.
I need a matrix form of an image.
that's it

Comment: then you should enlighten the world with whatever LogCat tells you. If you comment out the processing part after loading the image, what do you expect the program to do after loading the image? I'm confused.

Comment: The problem is that it cannot load the image, I mean it cannot read the file
The error is :
No impllemntation found for log org.opencv.highgui.Highgui.imread

Answer (score 0):

In comments you said you have exception : "No implementation found for native Lorg/opencv/highgui/Highgui;.imread_0".

The reason you can have it, you trying to call image load before dll was loaded. Please refer to : http://answers.opencv.org/question/24770/opencv-code-androidruntime-error/